# How do I use char double pointers with scanf?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So what I'm trying to do is scan a number of strings with the help of a char double pointer and I didn't find anywhere how to scanf it.

I thought that the logical way would be s[i], because going step by step it would be something like &**s to &*s[i] to s[i]. When trying to debug I get the error

**Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.**

```
char** s;
printf_s("Enter an integer: ");
scanf_s("%d", &n);
s = new char* [n];
printf_s("Enter %d arrays of characters: ", n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%s", s[i], 100);
    }
```

Comment: Don't.  Code C++ as C++ and use a `std::vector<std::string>` and `std::getline` with `std::cin`.

Comment: You never allocated `s[i]`. If you're using C++ though, follow what @NathanOliver said and also remove the C tag, if you're using C, then please remove the C++ tag

Comment: you only allocate an array of char pointers and never initialize them or allocate any actual strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What's wrong

Here is what's happening. You allocate your array of *n* `char *` with this line :

```
s = new char* [n];
```

What this line does is allocate the space to store *n* times a `char *`, i.e. you now can store *n* *pointers*

However, to store your user-inputted characters, each of these pointers is must be initialized so that they point to a memory area with enough space to store the inputted characters. Each pointer in `s`, i.e. `s[0]`, `s[1]`, etc. up to `s[n-1]` must be set to point to a memory area of suitable size to store your user input.

Here, you left the pointers **uninitialized** so in theory, their value is random. Your program crashes because it tries to write in a random memory location when you pass `s[i]` as an argument to `scanf_s`.

In your case Visual Studio filled them in them with a specific value of `0xCDCDCDCD` to help you detect uninitialized values.

There are several ways you can work around this problem :

### Using C++ functions

Since your post is tagged `C++` and you use `new`, I suppose you are coding in C++. You can use more convenient functions and data structures doing the dynamic allocation of memory and pointer management for you that are part of the standard library of C++. Here is what I suggest you look up:

- replace your `char*`s with [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), which stores string of characters and figures out automatically the storage part,
- replace your array of `char*` (i,e, `char**`) with a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which will store your strings in a dynamic array,
- use [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) and [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) in the `iostream` library instead of `scanf_s`to collect user input.

All these are very common C++ functions, so your favorite C++ tutorial or book should have examples on how to use them.

### Using C functions

If for some reason you don't want to use C++ functions , you can fix your code by allocating the elements of `s`. A simple way to do this is to assume that there is a maximum size to the strings your user will type (say 100 characters), so each pointer of `s` will be set to point to an allocated memory of 101 chars (remember we have to count the extra `\0` to mark the end of the string).

```
s = new char* [n];
const int max_chars = 101;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    s[i] = new char[max_chars];
}
```

In this case, as required by the documentation of [`scanf_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019) you must pass the size of your array of `char` (here it's 101). This will prevent your program from crashing if your user-input string is bigger than 100 characters. You can then check the **return value** of `scanf_s` to see if the read has succeeded.

Also, don't forget to deallocate the memory you allocated with `delete[]`, first by deallocating each of the `s[i]` then by deallocating `s`.

Answer (score 1):

`s[i]` is a *value* that you're passing to `scanf_s` to tell it where to store the result. It's an uninitialized value so the behavior is undefined. You need to allocate memory for it to point to of sufficient size (e.g. the 100 that you lied to `scanf_s` with) to store the result, but this is still awful because your program would crash with a runtime constraint violation if the input length exceeds that.

Basically you should not be using `scanf_s` for this. The string conversion specifiers are not usable without a field width limiter, and probably don'd do what you want anyway. Since you're writing C++, why aren't you using the C++ standard library functions (iostream, etc.) that would automate this correctly for you?

Comment: So I need to allocate memory with new also for every string (for every `s[i]`) then,right?
I'm working like this because it's a homework for college and we almost always use printf and scanf and I also thought it would be more interesting to try and do it like this and maybe get a better understanding of how the double pointers work.

Answer (score -1):

In C/C++, you can use the following code snippet:

```
  char **s = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*size);
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    s[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    scanf("%s",&s[i]);
  }
```

Comment: There is no C/C++ language.  This is incorrect C code and bad C++ code and should not be used.

Comment: Since `size` isn't defined anywhere you actually _can't_ use this snippet. And for several reasons you _should_ not use it. I mean, you don't even use `scanf_s` as in the question, so it's actually a big step back in terms of security. Also this code leaks memory. And finally an answer should include an explanation of _why_ or _how_ this works.

Comment: @churill 'size' is for reference, this is not executable code. Memory deallocation can be done & checkout the post title first:- "How do I use char double pointers with scanf?". There are many ways to do this, I showed one way of doing it.

Comment: Now it really looks like a snippet. But if you wrap it in a `main` it's no snippet but a whole program (which didn't work). The flaws mentioned above still exist and are in no way adressed in the answer. So I disagree, this is no way of doing it.